# Is there a way to make the browser break long lines of text?

Tags: browser, website

I find it annoying to read long texts within the browser because they spread across the whole width of the screen. I find myself resizing the browser window constantly to make reading more convenient.

1. Is there a way to make text in webpages conform to a certain width?
2. Is there a Firefox extension or Greasemonkey script that does that?

Comment: HTML (The language most webpages are written in) is designed to avoid this. It just shows the contents and the browser is supposed to format it. If that does not happen then something weird is going on. Can you give an example (as a link) of such a website which acts wrong?

Comment: The thing I mentioned is a normal behavior. But this is exactly the problem; the lines are fitted to the window size and you find yourself reading lines which are almost 13" long! (in Wikipedia for example).

Comment: Aye, lines are fitted to windows size. So there is not need to resize, since all text will be on screen. Both before and after a resize.

Comment: Resize your browser window. I use a little [utility](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer.html) on Windows which give me a drop-down menu of standard sizes I've defined. Plus the browser I use (Firefox) remembers its last size and position and returns to it the next time I restart it. It also has command-line arguments to control its initial size.

Comment: I'm sorry but I wouldn't describe the need for window resizing (or horizontal scrolling) as "normal behaviour" at all on desktop computers. My feeling is that you have, probably unintentionally, tweaked things to make window resizing (or horizontal scrolling) necessary. I suggest you test Firefox in safe mode (which implies, among other things, that no extensions will run) or create an additional profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Dr. Body Narrow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dr-body-narrow/) extension for Firefox. It's more popular, and has more features than the other option. It supports Firefox 3.5+.

> **About this Add-on:**
>
> Dr.Body Narrow helps you to read text on wide screens. It Provides
>   various options to limit current page width (so it won't occupy 100%
>   of window).
>
> In new versions you are able to choose one of 600, 760, 960, 1240,
>   1560, 1880 pixels on your choice, which one is more comfortable for
>   you.
>
> Dr.Body Narrow allows you to stick page to the left or right side
>   of the window, or center it - as you like.

---

You can use the [Page Width Resizer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/38806) script for Greasemonkey
   ([installation instructions](http://userscripts.org/about/installing)). It's very useful for wide screens,
   and the functionality of this script is actually very nice. It
   supports Firefox 4.0+.

> **Script Summary:**
>
> Adds translucent borders to both sides of the page. By
>   dragging one of the borders, you can change the width of each page
>   without resizing the window (preserving the page sizes in other tabs).